# Electric force in general relativity

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, forces, electric-fields

In general relativity, for two electrons in a space-time how do we define the electric force? Is it such that we have in classical physics or they go away from each other because of the curvature that exist beyond them?

Comment: I won't dupehammer this, but it is effectively a duplicate of [Maxwell's equations in curved spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70739/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maxwell's equations in curved spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70739/)

Comment: I guess that when metric enters the formulas,the curvature or the characteristics of space-time will be entered too.so it has a different formula with classical physics .

Comment: I am confused that by the presence of two electrons in a space-time ,first does the metric change?then the connections?then the curvature?or first the stress energy tensor, then the curvature,then the connections?and the metric doesn't change

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that General Relativity *is* classical. Perhaps the term you were going for was "non-relativistic"

Answer (score 1):

The Lorentz force experienced by a point particle reads
$$qF^{\mu\nu}u_\nu,$$
where $u_\nu$ is its four-velocity and $F^{\mu\nu}$ is the electromagnetic tensor. This means that the point-particle follows the equation of motion
$$m \frac{Du^\mu}{d \tau} = m\left(\ddot{x}^\mu + \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta} \dot{x}^\alpha \dot{x}^\beta\right) = q F^{\mu\nu} u_\nu,$$
where the dot denotes derivatives with respect to the proper time. As you can see, if there is no electromagnetic field (or charge), the point particles move in geodesics, and the effect of electromagnetism is to change their geodesic motion according to the Lorentz force.

Comment: Thanks,I think that every electron must change the space-time, because of its electric field,but I don't know does the presence of an electron first change the connections,or first the metric?and then the curvature of space-time? And these changes do not enter the above formulas?It's a little different from the previous question that is answered.

Comment: If you put a point particle in curved spacetimes and take Einstein's equations seriously, they should be black holes, with infinite density at one point in space. Usually what one does is to treat point particles as test particles, and solve their equations of motion in a given background. Keep in mind that the electric field generated by these particles can also affect the geometry of spacetime via the stress energy tenor of E.M., $T_{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{4\pi}\left(F_{\mu\alpha}F_{\nu}^\alpha -\tfrac{1}{4} g_{\mu\nu} F^{\alpha\beta}\right)$.

Comment: One could also try to model the internal states of the electron and assign a stress tensor to it, in addition to the stress tensor of electromagnetism, but then the dynamics of the electron would be entirely determined by its $T_{(e)}^{\mu\nu}$, and its equation of motion would not be the geodesic equation, instead it would be $\nabla_\mu T_{(e)}^{\mu\nu} + \nabla_\mu T_{E.M.}^{\mu\nu}=0$. This equation should be much harder to solve, but will give you the influence of curvature via the covariant derivative $\nabla_\mu$ and the influence of E.M. via  the $\nabla_\mu T_{E.M.}^{\mu\nu}$ term.

Comment: Thanks,is it true that a new observer can feel a new R (that is the summation of the R of the gravity and the R of the electric field)?

Comment: So does the observer consider new connections and maybe a new metric?

Comment: An observer will, in general, feel an $R$ that will already take into account the electric field via Einstein's equations, which automatically implement the fact that the metric changes in the presence of the electric field. It is then possible to define the contribution of electromagnetism to the spacetime curvature tensor as $R^{(EM)}_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} = R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} - R^{(BG)}_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}$, where $R^{(BG)}_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}$ is the curvature tensor of spacetime in the absence of charges.

Comment: However, it is important to mention that Einstein's equations are highly non-linear, and the $R^{(EM)}_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}$ term defined above will in general be a very complicated function of the electromagnetic tensors.